# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined even after initialization

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a interface `Weather`. I am trying to create an array of objects for interface inside my component. The following code is my interface:

```
export interface Weather {
    city: String;
    temp: String;
    description: String;
}
```

Now I am trying to create an array of objects inside my component, here is my component file:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Ng-Weather';
  weather: Weather[] = [];
  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) { }    
  search(cityName) {
    this.weatherService.getWeatherbyName(cityName)
      .subscribe(this.storeData);
  }
  storeData(data: Weather) {
    this.weather.push(data);
    console.log('weather: ' + this.weather);
  }
}
```

The error I am getting on my console is:
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass arrow function to subscribe to preserve the context of component class;
An arrow function does not create its own this, the this value of the enclosing execution context is used. For more read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

```
 .subscribe((data)=> this.storeData);
```

or

```
this.storeData.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 1):

`...subscribe(this.storeData.bind(this))`

or use arrow function

**[UPDATE]**

So, basically, what happens is a well known `this`-problem: at the moment when your `subscription` gets actual value, `this` doesn't point to component anymore but who knows to what (if to nothing particular, then to browsers `window` object). So, what you need to do is transfer (`bind`) the scope of `this` to the function that you supply to `subscribe` or you need to use, so called, arrow functions, because they don't create new scope; something like:

`...subscribe(data => {console.log(data)})`

Comment: can you describe why I should do this? Since I am beginner and need to understand more. Also can you explain the arrow function?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the returning data from the subscription. As dee zg said, you could use an arrow function like this:

```
this.weatherService.getWeatherbyName(cityName)
    .subscribe( data => {this.storeData(data);} );
```